# Triggertest , invalid statement

Tags: sql, oracle

*SOLVED* Forgot "Insert" before "or update" in the trigger.

```
 create or replace trigger biufer_bankkund
before insert or update on bankkund
for each row
begin
if NOT LENGTH (:NEW.PASSWD) = 6 then
raise_application_error
(-20001,'För låg ny lön!');
end if;
end;
```

So I created a trigger which is supposed to maintain passwords only containing 6 letters.

My guess is that that the trigger is incorrect, as i did 
Select*
from bankkund and there was data in it with a passwd with only 3 letters..

```
create or replace trigger biufer_bankkund
before update on bankkund
for each row
begin
if NOT LENGTH (:NEW.PASSWD) = 6 then
raise_application_error
(-20001,'För låg ny lön!');
end if;
end;
```

Then a procedure with the inparameters PNR,FNAMN,ENAMN,PASSWD.

```
create or replace procedure do_bankkund(
p_pnr in bankkund.pnr%type,
p_fnamn in bankkund.fnamn%type,
p_enamn in bankkund.enamn%type,
p_passwd in bankkund.passwd%type)
is
begin
insert into bankkund(pnr,fnamn,enamn,passwd)
values(p_pnr,p_fnamn,p_enamn,p_passwd);
end;
/
```

Everything went good, but did and triggertest, to test if entering more/less than 6 letters into PASSWD would return me an error with "the error text"). But I only got back "Invalid statement"

Anyone? 
Thank you

```
Triggertest  =   EXEC do_bankkund('691124-4478','Leena','Kvist','qwe');
```

Comment: Where does `TriggerTest` come from??? The SQL\*Plus syntax would be just `EXEC do_bankkund('691124-4478','Leena','Kvist','qwe');`.

Comment: Ur correct, misunderstanding.